# How to call 'like any' PostgreSQL function in JPQL

Tags: jpa

I have next issue:
I have list of names, based on which I want to filter.The problem is that I have not full names(Because I'm receiving them from ui), and I have, for example, this array= ['Joh', 'Michae'].

So, I want to filter based on this array.

I wrote query in PostgreSQL

```
select * from q_ob_person where name  like any (array['%Хомяченко%', '%Вартопуз%']);
```

And I want to ask how to write JPQL query gor this.

Is there an option to call postgresql function like any from JPQL?

Answer (score 2):

JPA 2.1 allows invocation of any SQL function using

```
FUNCTION(sqlFuncName, sqlArgs)
```

So you could likely do *something like* (note never tried this LIKE ANY you refer to, just play around with it)

```
FUNCTION("LIKE", FUNCTION("ANY", arrayField))
```

Obviously by invoking SQL functions specific to a particular RDBMS you lose database independence (in case that's of importance).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find more information about that